# mysql count rows in query containing LEFT JOIN hangs server

Tags: mysql, join, count, left-join, freeze

I have two tables. Table `people` with 16500 rows, `visits` with 17000 rows.
My query contains LEFT JOIN because I have to link `visits` to `people`. I'm aware that if there is people record without visits record those visits columns will be NULL.

This simple query works like a charm.

```
SELECT * FROM people LEFT JOIN visits ON people.id = visits.id_people;
```

But **when I try to count** returned rows, **MySQL hangs** (or counting) 30+ seconds or **until I kill it**. That is not acceptable in production environment.

Here are different methods I tried to use for counting resulted rows, but all of them has the same hanging result.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people LEFT JOIN visits ON people.id = visits.id_people;

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM people LEFT JOIN visits ON people.id = visits.id_people;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Strange is that those methods are working fine on small testing tables (5 and 5 rows).

Can anyone help?

Comment: 1. Have you got indexes on people.id and visits.id_people ? 2. Can you have visits without any link to people ? 3. Can people have more than one visit ?

Comment: can you run EXPLAIN on the query?

Comment: Awesome! Thank you guys, that pointed me the right direction. I had no idea that visits has to have two indexes. One PRIMARY (that I knew) and one INDEX set on visits.id_people. I just assumed I defined it using ON. Now it's working lightning-speed! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating a new MySQL table you can specify a column to index by using the INDEX term.Indexes are something extra that you can enable on your MySQL tables to increase performance
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/1382791/Optimizing-MySQL-Queries-and-Indexes.htm
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-indexes.htm view this it gives you much idea..

cheers